# Georeferencing multiple rasters to World files in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, gdal, georeferencing

I've got exactly 56 tiffs to georeference. Each raster has its unique TFW world file. I'd like  to automate this process. Each raster has it's unique name which is consistent with world file name (eg. HT.tif and HT.tfw). I searched for Python function on update georeferencing and closest I've got was 'Warp' function in Data Management but it's not exactly it. I know I can do it manually bu adding each raster to ArcMap and update georeferencing this way but I'd have to do that 56 times.

Apart from ArcGIS perhaps there is a GDAL option?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: are your tifs [geotiff's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF)?

Comment: why doesn't Warp work?

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure if I understand the question...  If the tfw file already exists, but the tiff and you want to produce a geotiff with the georeferencing in it, then you can use something like gdal_translate.  If you need to define the projection information then, gdalwarp should work.

ArcGIS also lets you use the tools in models so you can make a model, set the parameters you need then export this to a script that can be run directly.  Depending upon what you need a simple batch file can finish it off.